Bump/normal/displacment only applied to ambient occlusion
Hi I'm kind of working towards a shoreline effect shader and testing out having foam and water separated using the ambient occlusion node.
What I can't figure out is how to have a normal or bump or displacment for the foam separated in any way similar to the diffuse part of the shader using the ambient occlusion node.
I can only combine the two maps not have the foam bump/normal/displacement only used where the foam shows up and the water bump/normal/displacement only show up where the water is.
Below are some pics of the combined and normal renders to show what I mean.



You just make your two separate shaders and then select all the relevant nodes and turn them into a group. Then you just use the AO node to mix between the two.



Final result:


Thanks so much, that worked.

Awesome! if this answers your question then can you accept it as the answer so that it gets removed from the unanswered question pool?
